# Unit testing views in dropwizard

Tags: java, unit-testing, dropwizard

I'm trying to test that a view returned from a drowpizard resource is assembled correctly. Specifically, the view to add a user has a field that allows a password checker to reject an attempt to build a user if it fails to meet certain rules. The view works great when deploying and running the webapp, and specifying a bad password, but when I try to unit test it, it throws a web application exception saying there's no message body writer for the view.

My unit test is pretty plain:

```
@Test
public void testBadPassword(){
    ClientResponse response = null;
    try {
         response=client().resource("/users").post(ClientResponse.class, createUserParameters);
         Status status = response.getClientResponseStatus();
         assertEquals(Status.SEE_OTHER, status);
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get back a server 500 error, which has buried within the following:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.seeker.stm.resources.views.AddUserView, and Java type class com.seeker.stm.resources.views.AddUserView, and MIME media type text/html was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
```

The resource dealing with the request and generating the views and responses looks like this:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    public Object addUser(@FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password,
        @FormParam("email") String email){
    Set<String> passwordErrors = passwordChecker.checkValidity(password, username, email);
    if (!passwordErrors.isEmpty()) {            
        return new AddUserView(userDAO.getAllActive(), passwordErrors);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I can understand the exception (the writers it knows about, like StringProvider and ByteArrayProvider, don't work for a response or a view or something) but I'd more like to know how to properly test a resource that can return either a response code, or a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `addProvider(ViewMessageBodyWriter.class);` to your `setUpResources`.

`ViewMessageBodyWriter` is added as a provider by `ViewBundle`, which is why it works in your service (where you probably have `bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle());`).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that exception. I now get a similar exception about not having a message body READER, and looking through the view bundle, there doesn't appear to be anything like that. Is there another provider I need to add, or some sort of annotation I need to provide, to get the unit test to work?

Comment: Looks like Coda got you fixed up: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/fGjawn1HTzQ

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dropwizard 0.8.0-rc3 and my views are freemarker template based.  I tried the above and kept getting exceptions.  What finally got it working for me was calling

```
.addProvider(new ViewMessageBodyWriter(new MetricRegistry(), Collections.singleton(new FreemarkerViewRenderer())))
```

on my `ResourceTestRule.builder()`.